# storing of URL in Query String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, query-string

I am working with javascript (angular js), when a user clicks an advertisement regarding a feature of an app it should redirect to link given in the advertisement after login into the app.

How to store the link in the advertisement in query string and pass it after login.

Comment: Can you post your existing HTML/JS ?

Comment: if (!$localStorage.token) {
        //store url in query string


        window.location.href = ENV.login_uri;

    }

    }